# Code if then statement by only using $ utility

Tags: gams-math

How can I code this 'if' conditions in GAMS?

```
Set    j/1*10/ 
       S/1*6/;
   Parameter  
          b(s,j)    export this from excel
          U(s,j)    export  from excel 
          M(s)/1 100,2 250,3 140,4 120,5 132/    export from excel
    ;

table b(s,j)

    1   2   3   4   5   6    7   8    9    10
1   3   40  23  12  9   52   9   14   89   33  
2   0   0   42   0  11  32  11   15   3    7
3   10  20  12   9  5  30   14   5   14    5
4   0   0   0    9  0   3   8    0   13    5
5   0  10  11  32  11  0    3    1   12    1
6   12  20  2   9  15   3   14   5   14    5
;
 u(s,j)=0;
 u(s,j)$(b(s,j))=1;

  Variable delta(j);  "binary"
```

After solving a model I got the value of delta ( suppose delta(1)=1, delta(5)=1). Then  Set A is

```
A(j)$(delta.l(j)=1)=Yes;  (A={1,5})
```

I want to calculate parameter R(s) according to the following :

```
 If  there is no j in A(j)  s.t.  j in u(s,j) then R(s)=M(s)
 Else if  there is a j in A(j) s.t. j in u(s,j) then R(s)=min{b(s,j): j in A(j) , j in u(s,j) }
```

Then R(1)=3, R(2)=11,R(3)=5, R(4)=120, R(5)=11,R(6)=12.

Is it possible to code this ' if then ' statement  only by $  utility?
 Thanks

Comment: Hi @linkho -- why not if/else conditions? Seems ideal for this and more readable.

Comment: Hi @Berenger , As I thought, I could not write with $. I had problems with using if /else too. I don't know if I need to write R (j, s) to calculate R, or can we work only with 's'( write R (s))?

Comment: I think some example data and intended output might help. Perhaps you could add that? For instance, in your if statement, do you mean no `j` in `A(j)` s.t. a nonzero value of `j` exists in `U(s,j)` across all `j`? That is, if `A(j)` is specified for `j` `1-20` and `u(s,j)` is specified for `j` `21-100` then it binds? Or just for the specific `j` in question? That is, if `j=1` is defined in both `A(j)` and `u(s,j)` then it binds, and repeat for `j=2`, `j=3` and so on.

Comment: I edited My question. in fact U(s,j) are a nonzero value in every scenarios.

Comment: Cool, think I get what you are after. Have put a solution up.

Comment: @Berenger Thanks! so is this work too? A(j)$(delta.l(j)=1)=yes;  R(s) = M(s);   R(s) = smin(j$(A(j) and U(s,j)), b(s,A));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following on from the comments, I think this should work for you.

(Create a parameter that mimics your variable delta just for demonstration:)

```
parameter delta(j);
delta('1') = 1;
delta('5') = 1;
```

### With loop and if/else:

Create parameter R(s). Then, looping over s , pick the minimum of b(s,A) across set A where b(s,A) is defined if the sum of b(s,A) is not zero (i.e. if one of the set is non-zero. Else, set R(s) equal to M(s).

Note, the loop is one solution to the issue you were having with mixed dimensions. And the $(b(s,A)) needs to be on the first argument of smin(.), not on the second argument.

```
parameter R(s);

loop(s,

    if (sum(A, b(s,A)) ne 0,

        R(s) = smin(A$b(s,A), b(s,A));

    else

        R(s) = M(s);
    );

);
```

### With $ command only (@Lutz in comments):

```
R(s)$(sum(A, b(s,A)) <> 0) = smin(A$b(s,A), b(s,A)); 
R(s)$(sum(A, b(s,A)) = 0) = M(s);
```

Gives:

```
----     56 PARAMETER R  

1   3.000,    2  11.000,    3   5.000,    4 120.000,    5  11.000,    6  12.000
```

Comment: Since the initial question was about doing this with a $-condition, I would like to add, that the following should actually do the same (if I did not miss a point):

    R(s)$(sum(A, b(s,A)) <> 0) = smin(A$b(s,A), b(s,A));
    R(s)$(sum(A, b(s,A)) = 0)  = M(s);

In general, GAMS has a better performance, when doing plain parallel assignments (without a loop or similar). Here, this probably makes no difference, but on a bigger scale (more elements in s for example), you might see the difference.

Comment: @lutz , am I understand right? Does not using a loop in large sclae elements make the code run faster?

Comment: In general, yes. Or maybe formulated differently: Using a loop could make the code slower (but it does not have to). I would recommend to use loops only, if needed.

Comment: Yeah this is what I was going to come back to following the latest comment on the question. Thanks for adding @Lutz. I’ve edited the answer.